# How to access a global name that is the same as a function parameter in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a module that has a similar interface to numpy, along with a "dtype" analogue. In numpy, "dtype" is the name of a class and also a parameter to various functions. I would like to be able to write functions that accept a parameter "dtype" but are also able to create objects of class dtype.

In the example below I am trying to create a "number" class which is created with a dtype parameter that can either be an object of type dtype, or something else which can be passed to a dtype constructor.

```
class dtype():
    def __init__(self, width=1):
        self.width = width

class number():
    def __init__(self, value, dtype=None):
        self.value = value
        dtype_ = dtype
        global dtype
        if isinstance(dtype_, dtype):
            self.dtype = dtype_
        elif dtype_ is None:
            self.dtype = dtype()
        else:
            self.dtype = dtype(dtype_)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'number(value={},width={})'.format(self.value, self.dtype.width)

v1 = number(1)

t2 = dtype(2)
v2 = number(1, t2)

v3 = number(1, 3)
```

This does not work:

```
    global dtype
    ^
SyntaxError: name 'dtype' is parameter and global
```

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do in Python, or is NumPy able to do this only because it's written in C?

Comment: Is there a reason behind calling the parameter the same as the class and so shadowing it? call the param `dtypeparam` and you are golden. (not quite sure why this is fiercly dv)

Comment: @PatrickArtner: Calling it `dtypeparam` makes passing parameters by keyword way more awkward. I know I'd hate it if I had to write `numpy.array([1, 2, 3], dtypeparam='int64')`.

Comment: I wonder why this question has attracted so many downvotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual case in large libraries like NumPy is that different functionality would be implemented in different submodules of the package, and there would be no global/local name clash because most of the functions that wanted to use the name as an argument name would be in different submodules from where the name is used as a global. Here's a toy example:

```
# mypackage/__init__.py
from .a import thing
from .b import thing_user

# mypackage/a.py
class thing:
    ...

# mypackage/b.py
from . import a
def thing_user(thing):
    do_something_with(thing)    # the argument
    do_something_with(a.thing)  # the class
    ...
```

(NumPy does also automatically avoid the issue in the parts written in C, but this is why the parts written in Python can have parameters named `dtype` without a problem - `dtype` isn't a global variable there.)

If you want to stick with a single file, the simplest option would be to use a secondary global to avoid the name clash, as long as you don't need to support reassigning or mocking the global:

```
class thing:
    ...

_thing = thing

def thing_user(thing):
    do_something_with(thing)   # the argument
    do_something_with(_thing)  # the class
```

If that doesn't fit your use case, you can have a function access a global variable shadowed by a local by accessing its module's `globals()` dict directly, or by using a helper function:

```
class thing:
    ...

def _get_thing():
    return thing

def thing_user(thing):
    do_something_with(thing)               # the argument
    do_something_with(globals()['thing'])  # the class
    do_something_with(_get_thing())        # the class again
```

Comment: Thanks. I am happy with the workaround for now and ended up making a file-scope reference `_dtype_class = dtype` which let me do what I wanted to.